# Rive Animation.asset stop animating after setState

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, statefulwidget, rive

I want to use a Rive to make animated icons in NavigationBar.
I have a NavigationBar widget in StatefulWidget. When I call setState, destinations (in NavigationBar) is redrawn and the Rive animation is interrupted and flickers.
How to use a Rive with NavigationBar?

I tried move Rive.asset to other widget. Its not working, stateful always do initState when parent widget call serState.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Me too, here's how I solved it for myself

#### Problem

I had a method returning a widget, that included several Rive Animations from a "Asset" folder.

When setState was called, the animations could not be triggered (event listener did not respond) and the animations did not animate, but was just statically shown.

#### Solution

###### Even though it sounds like a strange solution:

I turned my method (mentioned earlier) into a Future, and used a FutureBuilder. After this, it worked great.

#### Why?

With some knowledge of making Rive Animations now and not claiming to be an expert, I can only guess.

I think, that the FutureBuilder just makes sure to make a new Widget, and after setState the Widget is "broken". So, by making a new Widget, I do not need to deal with the "broken" one.

I should say, however, that I did not see any performance change from this solution.